# Bulk update in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing data about some users.

Many of them use our in house email system at OLDHOST.com. We have updated to a newer system at NEWHOST.com. All the users usernames are the same, so if you had dave@OLDHOST.com, you are now dave@NEWHOST.com

Is there a better way to change all the email fields in the users table without selecting all the rows in say PHP, then checking if the email has OLDHOST in it, then replacing the string to NEWHOST?

Is there a baked in awesome SQL statement to help with this?

---

Example of some of the table (simplified)

```
id | firstname | surname | email
------------------------------------------------
1  | dave      | smith   | a21dsmith@OLDHOST.com
2  | barry     | jones   | a21bjones@OLDHOST.com
```

etc.

All that needs to be changed is any emails that contain OLDHOST (Not all do) to NEWHOST.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to replace the relevant part of each string within an update statement, grabbing the hostname substring after the `@` with a REPLACE, and replacing it.

```
UPDATE table SET email=REPLACE(email,'OLDHOST.com', 'newhost.com');
```

Note: REPLACE() *is* case-sensitive, so you can use `LOWER(email)` inside the REPLACE function if you need to catch all case possibilities, as below:

```
UPDATE table SET email=REPLACE(LOWER(email),'oldhost.com', 'newhost.com');
```

This will also convert all your email addresses to lowercase, so be aware of that :)

Comment: No, sorry - it's an email address stored for each user in  a column called email as a string.

Comment: I like the way that SO is becoming an incredible reference for every possible question.

Also, I can't believe I've never heard of REPLACE!